# Regression Elasticities with categorical variables

Tags: regression

I'm regressing a continuous variable (y) on a categorical (x=0,1,2) variable.
Is it possible (or even make sense?) to derive an elasicity of y on x?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In general, the elasticity is defined as a ratio of percentages ($Y$ is the dependent variable and $X$ is the regressor)

$$\varepsilon_{Y,X} = \frac {\text {% change in } Y}{\text {% change in } X}$$

So the percentage change must be meaningful in order for the elasticity to be meaningful. When $X$ is categorical, then its percentage change may be meaningful, may be not: if $X$ measures some discrete quantity (like "number of children", "number of deaths", in general "number of...") then its percentage change makes perfect sense. But if it represents an *ordinal*  and not cardinal ranking (e.g. 1 = good, 2 = very good), or if it is a mapping of qualitative states (like e.g. $0$ = no color, $1$ = red, $2$ = blue) then the percentage change has no meaning, and so neither does the elasticity.

If the "meaningfulness criterion" is satisfied, then in general the concept of elasticity appropriate for discrete-valued data is the [Arc elasticity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_elasticity)

$$\varepsilon_{Y,X} = \frac {(y_2-y_1)(x_2+x_1)}{(y_2+y_1)(x_2-x_1)}$$

where the subscripts denote specific points, and where we essentially use the mid points of the intervals involved (but the two divisions by $2$ cancel out). In a linear regression setting where we have estimated a *constant* marginal effect, $\hat \beta$, this marginal effect substitutes for the two difference-terms in the above expression and the elasticity becomes

$$\varepsilon_{Y,X} = \hat \beta\frac {(x_2+x_1)}{(y_2+y_1)}$$

Comment: Thanks Alecos and indeed thanks Analyst too. The ordinal variables that I'm using are indeed ordinal (e.g., demo=1, autocracy=0) so it doesn't fulfill your "meaningfulness" criteria and falls foul of the marginal criteria of Analyst.

Comment: I would say that in your case, going form Autocracy to Democracy gives an "infinite" percentage change and a "zero" elasticity, results which, while meaningless mathematically, have a strangely intuitive flavor philosophically...

Comment: Sorry perhaps the better word would have been categorical variable, rather than ordinal.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dependent variable Y_i on log-scale, then change in the independent variable measures percentage change.

If IV is also in log-scale then parameters are already elasticities.

You could perhaps say that that coefficient in categorical IV measures elasticity as compared with belonging to the reference class when Y_i is in log-scale.

But if elasticity must mean marginal change in the DV with respect to change in the IV, then it cannot be elasticity since marginal change is not possible.